# jenkins pipeline warnings graph

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I started to migrate some jobs in jenkins to pipeline execution.

Is there any chance to see the [warnings](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) graph in [multi branch pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) jobs? Within my older projects I can configure the graphs with "Configure the trend graph" option. These option will crash in the pipeline syntax tool.

Is there any option to make the graph visible?

I have in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage ('Warnings gcc') {
    step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canResolveRelativePaths: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', messagesPattern: '', parserConfigurations: [[parserName: 'GNU Make + GNU C Compiler (gcc)', pattern: 'error_and_warnings.txt']], unHealthy: ''])
}   

stage ('Warnings clang') {
    step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canResolveRelativePaths: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', messagesPattern: '', parserConfigurations: [[parserName: 'Clang (LLVM based)', pattern: 'error_and_warnings_clang.txt']], unHealthy: ''])
}
```

The reports will be generated but no graph is displayed.

UPDATE: Now it still did not work but it is also impossible to use the snipped generator for the warnings plugin.

Entering a file name in the snipped generator for the warning plugin results in a java null pointer exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:236)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:362)
  some more lines follows ...
```

Mentioned in the revision log for the warnings plugin V 4.56:

> Fixed deactivation of trend graphs (using the analysis collector plug-in)

But I use 4.57 and it still did not display any graph!

I posted the problem also to jenkins [user list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/JqUO2lM5JQ0) (no feedback for weeks) and also added [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39533) and [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39532)

Can anyone reproduce the problem or is the multi-branch pipeline simply still broken at all? Seems to be that there are not so much users for this plugin...

Comment: Please add the link to your mail to the list as reference. Thanks

Comment: It works for me with a pipeline job. Did you test the recent version?

Answer (score 1):

These issues have been resolved with the latest versions of both Jenkins, the pipelines plugin[s], and the plugins you have mentioned above.

Additionally, the bugs you specifically reported have been resolved:

1. [[FIXED JENKINS-39553] Make GitHub plugin BuildableItem aware (#153)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/analysis-core-plugin/commit/af4723277b22eed1b1c776865ed9d1f510546c0c)
2. [[FIXED JENKINS-39532] Do not access the workspace for pipelines](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/commit/bd2e945b329ed86af1b5ab52358c87e50e3fb4aa)

Update your Jenkins instance and all of your plugins (some of them have interdependencies on others) and after the suggested restart you should be able to display the graph successfully.